# optimization of permutation algorithm

Tags: java, permutation

A "hexgram" consists of 6 lines. Each line is either "-------" or "--- ---".
I want to show all possible hexgrams. It's Math.pow(2, 6) = 64 hexgrams.
Is there a better way to code it? Maybe recursive implementation?

If I want to show all "octgrams" (256) I have to add 2 for-loops again.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] hexgrams = new String[2];

    hexgrams[0] = "-------\n";
    hexgrams[1] = "--- ---\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j<2; j++) {

            for(int k = 0; k<2; k++) {

                for(int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {

                    for(int m = 0; m<2; m++) {

                        for(int n = 0; n<2; n++) {

                            System.out.println(hexgrams[i] + hexgrams[j] + hexgrams[k] + hexgrams[l] + hexgrams[m] + hexgrams[n]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a recursive implementation and compare the two approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"?  If you are trying to make the code faster, there probably isn't a way.  The performance will be dominated by the time taken to write the output.

Comment: Do I really have to write 8 for loops to show all octgrams? Maybe there is a more elegant way.

Comment: So what do you mean by optimize?  And what do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @Henry How would the code look like? Sorry, I am a noob.

Comment: @StephenC That, what Henry wrote. A smarter, shorter or even faster way to solve the problem.

Comment: This is homework, right? The purpose of the homework was probably to teach recursion. Asking for us to write the code for you would go against the whole idea of homework.

Comment: So which of "smarter", "shorter" or "faster" are you optimizing for.  Seriously, you can't do all three at the same time!

Comment: "smarter": use recursion or the 'binary nature' of the problem; "shorter": use a loop to run each of the 8 loops (need an array to store the 8 indices); "faster": probably just 8 loops

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: I am a beginner. How would this recursion look like? And how can you use 1 loop to run the 8 loops with an array?  I saw the binary nature. It's like putting true or false in 6 lines and print every possible creation.

Comment: recursion: the method calls itself, just changing an index or so; loop: the first loop goes from 0 to 7 representing the position, the inner loop changes the index at that position - this is a bit too broad to be explained in a comment

Comment: *"this is a bit too broad to be explained in a comment"* - I disagree.  You have explained it well :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If you're trying to delete your post (just judging from the edit that got reverted), you can do that. But editing it to contain just "...." is not the way to do it.

Comment: @yshavit it canot be deleted if it has upvoted/multiple answers.  It will have to remain until prof's anti-cheat scripts have detected it

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, these are just binary patterns, so you could just take the numbers between 0 and 2^n (2^6 for hexagrams), generate bit representations, and replace the zeroes and ones with the required patterns:

```
int n = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
    String binary = String.format("%" + n + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(i))
                          .replace(' ', '0');
    String gram = binary.replace("0", "--- ---\n")
                        .replace("1", "-------\n");

    System.out.println(gram);
}
```

For octograms or any other n-grams, you just have to change the value of the `n` variable.

Comment: This optimizes for "smarter" ... not "faster".  And it doesn't actually generate N-grams in the form the OP is asking for.

Comment: @StephenC OP is asking for standard I'Ching hexagrams like `--   -`, `--- --` and so on. How does my code not generate those?

Comment: Read the Question again.  That is NOT what he is asking for.  And not wht his code produces.

Comment: @StephenC Yup, you were absolutely right. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you.
Do you know a way to implement it with recursion?

Comment: Sure, but someone already spelled it out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the correlation between the nGram and binary numbers you can quite easily generate them with simple loops.

```
private static final String[] GRAMS = {"-------","--- ---"};
private static final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.ONE.add(BigInteger.ONE);

private List<List<String>> nGrams(int n) {
    List<List<String>> nGrams = new ArrayList<>();
    BigInteger count = TWO.pow(n);
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(count) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        List<String> nGram = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            nGram.add(i.testBit(j)?GRAMS[1]:GRAMS[0]);
        }
        nGrams.add(nGram);
    }
    return nGrams;
}

private void test(int i) {
    System.out.println("nGrams("+i+")");
    nGrams(i).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    test(6);
    test(8);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't compile it.